# React and Typescript Custom hook for Api request (being called twice and not mapping to type)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api

I found an online example of a custom api service hook with typescript that seemed to make sense to me so I tried applying it to my needs. There are a couple things that are happening that don't make sense to me. First off, when I log out the data coming back from the api, it's being logged twice which I don't understand.

Secondly, when I log out service.payload.results, 'results' is undefined, but if I log just service.payload it logs an array as expected (except twice). I'm trying to type the results of my api call and enforce the shape on the data. I can't figure out what it is. Here is my code. Please see if you can spot anything that I'm missing or clearly do not understand.

1. Domain Types (Visitor.ts):

```
export interface Visit {
  id: string;
  visited: string;
}

export interface Visitor {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  visits: Array<Visit>;
}
```

2. Service Types (Service.ts):

```
interface ServiceInit {
  status: "init";
}
interface ServiceLoading {
  status: "loading";
}
interface ServiceLoaded<T> {
  status: "loaded";
  payload: T;
}
interface ServiceError {
  status: "error";
  error: Error;
}
export type Service<T> =
  | ServiceInit
  | ServiceLoading
  | ServiceLoaded<T>
  | ServiceError;
```

3. Custom Hook:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import { Service } from "../types/Service";
import { Visitor } from "../types/Visitor";

export interface Visitors {
  results: Visitor[];
}

const useVisitorService = () => {
  const [result, setResult] = useState<Service<Visitors>>({
    status: "loading",
  });
  const url: string = "api/visitors";
  const config = {
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const requestData = async function () {
      try {
        const res = await Axios.get(url, config);
        setResult({ status: "loaded", payload: res.data });
      } 
      catch (error) {
        setResult({ status: "error", error });
      }
    };
    requestData();
  }, []);

  return result;
};

export default useVisitorService;
```

4. Component that is using the hook (VisitList.tsx) :

```
import React from "react";
import useVisitorService from "../services/useVisitorService";

const VisitList: React.FC<{}> = () => {
  const service = useVisitorService();

  if (service.status === "loaded") {
    // this logs the expected array of objects from server (twice)
    console.log(service.payload);
  }

  //this errors because results is undefined
  return (
    <div>
      {service.status === "loading" && <div>Loading...</div>}
      {service.status === "loaded" &&
        service.payload.results.map((visitor) => (
          <div key={visitor.id}>{visitor.name}</div>
        ))}
      {service.status === "error" && (
        <div>Error.</div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default VisitList;
```

Comment: At the risk of being spammy, you *might* like [react-ketting](https://github.com/badgateway/react-ketting). It has some good hooks and will also de-duplicate GET requests even if they are from unrelated react components.

Comment: I will look at this to see if it has value to me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky one and I'm not entirely sure what's going on. Can you set up a sandbox which has the full url to fetch?

The potential problem that I see may or may not be an issue, depending on what the returned `res` object looks like.  I suspect that you are setting `service.payload` instead of `service.payload.results`, but I could be wrong.

Through your types, you have said that a successful result looks like this:

```
interface ServiceLoaded {
    status: "loaded";
    payload: {
        results: Visitor[];
    }
}
```

where payload **must** have a property `results` which is an array of `Visitor` objects.

This is not explicitly stated or verified in your code, which leaves it prone to errors.  You are setting the `payload` to `res.data` which could be any type.

```
setResult({ status: "loaded", payload: res.data });
```

Does `res.data` contain a property `results` that lists the visitors?  If it merely returns a list of visitors, you need to assign it to the `results` property yourself, and this would be the source of your troubles.  (Or you need to change your type/interface Visitors so that is just an array Visitor[] and not an object containing the array.)

```
setResult({ status: "loaded", payload: results: { res.data } });
```

Without knowing what your `res.data` actually looks like, I can suggest that you use a typescript type guard to verify it, since the Axios `res.data` currently has type `any`.  That way you know that `payload.results` will always be defined if `service.status === "loaded"`.  If Axios returns an unexpected result, `setResult` should store an error.

Your type guard is something like this.  I am just checking that property `results` exists, but you could get a lot more detailed and check that it is an array and that every element is a Vistor.

```
const isValidPayload = (payload: any): payload is Visitors => {
  return typeof payload === "object" && "results" in payload;
}
```

Your `requestData` function now looks something like, where we are still catching errors returned from Axios, but also catching errors due to invalid responses.

```
    const requestData = async function () {
        try {
          const res = await Axios.get(url, config);
          if ( isValidPayload(res.data) ) {
            setResult({ status: "loaded", payload: res.data});
          } else {
            setResult({ status: "error", error: {
              name: "Invalid Format",
              message: "API results must contain an array of Visitor objects",
            }});
          }
        } 
        catch (error) {
          setResult({ status: "error", error });
        }
      };
```